# Finding the average of IntegerField

Tags: python, django, rest

I'm trying to create a new datafield that stores the value according to the average of the 3 fields and also want to use the orderby in the views.py file

```
class TodoList(models.Model):username = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
title = models.TextField(max_length = 100)
num1 = models.IntegerField()
num2 = models.IntegerField()
num3 = models.IntegerField()
#average = (num1 + num2 + num3)/3  -> NoneType error
```

I'm trying to create a new datafield that stores the value according to the average of the 3 fields and also want to use the orderby in the views.py file

```
def profile(request, pk):
user_object = User.objects.get(username = pk)
user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user = user_object) #user_profile has the things related to that usertodolist = TodoList.objects.filter(username = pk).order_by('average')

context = {
    'user_object' : user_object,
    'user_profile' : user_profile,
    'todolist' : todolist,
}
return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

I tried using the property function, but wasn't able to order_by from that function. But was able to pass it in the html page

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

#average = (num1 + num2 + num3)/3  -> You can't do this, Model class is just for defining the schema of the table.

You will have to calculate the average separately and send it in your model

```
class TodoList(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    title = models.TextField(max_length = 100)
    num1 = models.IntegerField()
    num2 = models.IntegerField()
    num3 = models.IntegerField()
    average = models.DecimalField()
```

Run your migrations, then pass the data from where you are creating the TodoList object.

It probably will be in your views. So, in your views do

```
num1 = 123
num2 = 321
num3 = 231
average = (num1 + num2 + num3 )/ 3
todo = TodoList.objects.create(
    username = "Any username",
    title = "Any title",
    num1 = num1,
    num2 = num2,
    num3 = num3,
    average = average
)
```

Comment: I added this line average = (num1 + num2 + num3)//3 in my views function.
It shows  *unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'str' and 'int'*

Comment: first thing is doing "//" won't give you average. if num1=1, num2=2, num3=2, then it will be 5/3=1.666, but doing // will give you 5/3=1,

Comment: you getting unsupported operand error because your num's might be in string, and your are trying to divide string with an integer (3), make sure that the value in num variable are in integer, you can typecast it by doing this int(num1), int(num2), int(num3) then divide them by 3.